# When does a sleeve become a conduit, and how much can I fit in a sleeve?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

According to National Electrical Code, the conduit percentage fill table does not apply to sections of conduit used to provide protection from physical damage (sleeve).

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 9 Tables
>
> **Notes to Tables**
>
> (2) Table 1 applies only to complete conduit or tubing systems
> and is not intended to apply to sections of conduit
> or tubing used to protect exposed wiring from physical
> damage.

However, I wasn't able to find anywhere that defines when sections of conduit become a complete conduit system.  When the code says "sections" does it actually mean a *section* of conduit, so it would be a 10' length for example? Is it a "section" until it's attached to fittings or boxes?

Once I determine if it's a section or not, how do I determine how many conductors can fit?  Since the code says Table 1 does not apply, does that mean I should use the 100% fill values to determine fill?

Comment: Found this [somewhere](http://www.ecmag.com/section/codes-standards/knowledge-beats-experience): "A sleeve is [...] not connected to enclosures."

Comment: From my experience, the local codes are usually loose enough where the code official usually gets to say what they want in regards to determinations like these and if a sleeve is allowed, then common sense should take over and an appropriate fill table be applied based on the application.